# JavaScript проверка на делимость на 10 и 100

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как можно проверить равняется ли переменная 10, 20, 30 и тд. или 100, 200, 300 и тд. Проще говоря, как проверить наличие нуля и двух нулей в конце числа?

```
var x;
function(){
    x++;
    if (x>9 && /*проверка на ноль в конце*/ || x>99 && /*проверка на два нуля в конце*/) 
    {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Остаток от деления на 10 и 100 вас определенно спасут.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, мог бы и ответ написать

Answer (score 3):

Нужно проверять остаток от деления на степень десятки

```js
function isDecDivide(ANum) {
  var res = 10;
  while (ANum % res == 0)
    res *= 10;
  return res / 10;
}

console.log(isDecDivide(9));
console.log(isDecDivide(90));
console.log(isDecDivide(900));
console.log(isDecDivide(9000));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через остаток от деления **%**

Или привести к строке:

```
    var x = '100010';
    x.substr(-2);
    if (x == '00') {
...
    }

    var x = '100010';
    x.substr(-1);

    if (x == '0') {
...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

(Вредный совет)

Остаток от деления это слишком просто и очевидно, лучше используйте регулярки!.

```
var x = 1000
var match = x.toString(10).match(/^[1-9]0+$/)
if( match !== null ) 
    console.log( x, 'number of zeros', match[0].length - 1  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо всем, я (о, глупец!) про остаток от деления не подумал.

```
var x = 0;
function() {
  x++;
  if (x > 0 && x % 10 == 0 && x < 100) {
    console.log(x);
  }
  else if (x % 100 == 0 && x < 1000) {
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```